# Splitting list item into two items in place with regex

Tags: python, regex, list, split, element

So I have input of a list with elements like this:

> "calendar year 2008  for construction  reconstruction  resurfacing &
>   repair of streets & roads"

and I'm iterating through the list. For each iteration, first I want to verify that the pattern INTspacespacefor is in the string, which I know I can do with:

```
re.search('\\d+\s\sfor',string)
```

Once I've confirmed a match on one of the elements, I want to split this element into two elements in place between the INT and the "for". Is there an easy way to do this?

So a sample output for this would be:

```
[item1,item2,...item10,"calendar year 2008","for construction reconstruction resurfacing & repair of streets & roads",item11,item12...]
```

Comment: The OP wrote the example phrase using double spaces, but the formatting tool did away with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use look behind and look ahead

```
re.split('(?<=\d)\s\s(?=for)',string)
```

Comment: nice! looks like I need a more in depth understanding of regex.

Comment: @Oliver Here's a good manual for look-ahead and look behind: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html